# C# integer passed as reference in callback?

Tags: c#, callback, int, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm having a bit of problem with callback and for loop,
say I have this code

```
public void DoSth(Action<QueryTextureResult> result, IEnumerable<string> arr)
{
    int totalData = 0;
    foreach (var element in arr) // let's say arr.Count() is 10
    {
        Action<Texture> onImageReceived = (texture) =>
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                var res = new QueryTextureResult()
                {
                    Texture = texture,
                    QueryId = queryId,
                    Index = totalData // why this one is always 10 if the callback takes time? 
                };

                result(res);

                Debug.Log("INdex: " + res.Index);
            }
        };

        imageManager.GetImage("http://image.url", onImageReceived);

        totalData++;
    }

}
```

As written in the comment, if I have 10 elements, it takes time for `result` to be called, why the `QueryTextureResult.Index` that I received will always be 10? Is it passed by reference? any way to fix this?

Comment: Variable is captured, they all share same memory address.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, `totalData` is captured, therefore all delegate will reference to same variable. At the end of the loop, `totalData` will have value of `10`, and then every delegate will read the same `totalData` and will get `10` as result.

The solution is to take a copy of the variable before pass it to delegate, so every delegate has it's own copy.

```
foreach (var element in arr) // let's say arr.Count() is 10
{
    var copy = totalData;
    Action<Texture> onImageReceived = (texture) =>
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            var res = new QueryTextureResult()
            {
                Texture = texture,
                QueryId = queryId,
                Index = copy // <== 
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `totalData` is closured and `onImageReceived` will be called asynchronously.

Assuming that you have 3 items, it may execute in the following order:

1. `onImageReceived` declared for item 1, which outputs `totalData`
2. `GetImage` is called for item 1
3. `totalData = 1`
4. `onImageReceived` declared for item 2, which outputs `totalData`
5. `GetImage` is called for item 2
6. `totalData = 2`
7. `onImageReceived` declared for item 3, which outputs `totalData`
8. `GetImage` is called for item 3
9. `totalData = 3`
10. Item 1 is complete, which calls `onImageReceived` event, which outputs `totalData`...which is 3 now
11. Item 2 is complete, which calls `onImageReceived` event, and `totalData` is 3 as well
12. The same for item 3

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it kinda make sense now. So I guess `Index = totalData` is populated only after `onImageReceived` called is it?

Comment: @andiwinata Yeah. You can just set two breakpoints: in the beginning of your `DoSth` method, and in the beginning of `onImageReceived` Action and see what happens :)